# Ambigious Column error when using #StandardSQL

Tags: google-bigquery

Here is a simple query that i want to run. I've Data_Dt column in both the tables that I Join on. How do i qualify Data_Dt with table name and dataset name to avoid Ambigious Column error? I can make it work in Legacy SQL but I want to switch to Standard SQL due to extensive function library support. Thanks in Advance for your help!

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  Data_Dt AS `Data_Dt`
FROM
  `testDataSet.Origination`
INNER JOIN
  `testDataSet.Transition`
ON
  `testDataSet.Origination`.`Loan_Num_Q` = `testDataSet.Transition`.`Loan_Num_Q`
GROUP BY
  `Data_Dt`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  a.Data_Dt AS Data_Dt
FROM `testDataSet.Origination` a
INNER JOIN `testDataSet.Transition` b
ON a.Loan_Num_Q = b.Loan_Num_Q
GROUP BY a.Data_Dt
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I wish I could make it work without using table alias. I build this query based on selected field and function formulas (sum, wavg, avg etc.). I might have to change them as well.

Comment: Ouch, I've been up voting helpers without actually marking them as answer. Thanks for pointing it out. voted up and accepted as answer.